# JavaScript image handler

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am using this JavaScript function in order to change image on click, but it is doing refresh all the time and go back to the original image.

this is the code I am using;

```
function showImage1() {; 
    document.getElementById('Image5').style.visibility = 'visible';
    document.getElementById('Img1').style.visibility = 'hidden';
}

<div>
    <input ID="Button1" type="image" src=" Resources/Icons/benefitBtn.png" OnClick="showImage1();"/>
</div>
```

Any suggestion please?

Comment: There is no jQuery in your example. I edited the title, question, and tags to reflect that.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What does "doing refresh all the time and go back to the original image" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<input ID="Button1" type="image" src="Resources/Icons/benefitBtn.png" onClick="showImage1();return false;"/>`

Adding return false should stop any submit nature. *If I understood correctly....* :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 function toggleImage(elementToShow,elementToHide){
    $("#" + elementToShow).show();
    $("#" + elementToHide).hide();
 }

 <div>
 <input ID="Button1" type="button" class="yourButtonClass" OnClick="showImage1('Image5','Img1');"/>
 </div>

 set your button's background image in your stylesheet.
```